# what is PAT exactly?

Tags: router, port, linux-networking, iproute2, masquerade

In attempt to understand PAT, I've setup the following setup where I have a **Linux Router** that `masquerades` from in internal interface to the external. Thus both **clients** are able to talk to outside **Server** with IP translation happening in the Linux Router PC.

```
  +---------------+
  | client 1      |
  | src port 4567 |--+
  +---------------+  | +--------+     +--------------+
                     +-| Linux  |-----| Server listen|
                     +-| Router |     | on port 9584 |
  +---------------+  | +--------+     +--------------+
  | client 2      |  |
  | src port 4567 |--+
  +---------------+
```

I did a simple echo call using `nc` from **client 1** and **client 2** to **Server PC** and noticed the source port of the packet was in fact `4567`. When I ran the `nc` with the same `src` port number from both clients, one connection cause the other to break! (The clients are different computers btw) so I had the assumption that `iproute` hides  the port number too and does some translation much like IP mapping. Is this problem fixable?

Comment: If you take the router out of the picture do you see the same behavior for your netcat connections?

Comment: I'm in a company network and the `src port` number gets changed on the way out. I say this because I do `tcpdump` on the server computer and I visually see that the `port` number is not `4567`.